# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "14"

Tags: postgresql

Probably a bit dumb question, but i'm stuck with it.

This is my dynamic INSERT query, using Spring's `getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject()`

```
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("INSERT INTO goods_temp (item_title, item_descr, item_email, item_phone, item_images, item_price, owner, dateTime_created, category_id, subcategory_id, repost_to, type_sell");
    if(condo.getTitle()!=null){sb.append(", condo_name");}
    if(condo.getAddress()!=null){sb.append(", condo_address");}
    if(condo.getCity()!=null){sb.append(", condo_city");}
    if(condo.getCountry()!=null){sb.append(", condo_country");}
    if(condo.getLatitude()!=null){sb.append(", condo_latitude");}
    if(condo.getLongitude()!=null){sb.append(", condo_longitude");}
    if(condo.getLocationType()!=null){sb.append(", condo_location_type");}
    if(item.getExtra_data()!=null){sb.append(", extra_data");}

    sb.append(") ");
    sb.append("VALUES ( ");
    sb.append("'"+item.getItemTitle().replaceAll("\'s", "").replaceAll("[-+.^:,']","").trim()+"'");
    sb.append(", '"+item.getItemDescr().trim()+"'");
    sb.append(", '"+item.getItemEmail().trim()+"'");
    sb.append(", '"+item.getItemPhone()+"'");
    sb.append(", '"+tempImgArray+"'");
    sb.append(", '"+item.getItemPrice()+"'");
    sb.append(", '"+item.getOwner()+"'");
    sb.append(", "+new Timestamp(item.getTimestamp().getTime()) );
    sb.append(", "+item.getCategory_id());
    sb.append(", "+item.getSubcategory_id());
    sb.append(", '"+tempRepostToArray+"'");
    sb.append(", "+item.getType_sell());


    if(condo.getTitle()!=null){sb.append(", '"+condo.getTitle()+"'");}
    if(condo.getAddress()!=null){sb.append(", '"+condo.getAddress()+"'");}
    if(condo.getCity()!=null){sb.append(", '"+condo.getCity()+"'");}
    if(condo.getCountry()!=null){sb.append(", '"+condo.getCountry()+"'");}
    if(condo.getLatitude()!=null){sb.append(", '"+condo.getLatitude()+"'");}
    if(condo.getLongitude()!=null){ sb.append(", '"+condo.getLongitude()+"'");}
    if(condo.getLocationType()!=null){sb.append(", '"+condo.getLocationType().stringValue()+"'");}
    if(item.getExtra_data()!=null){sb.append(", '"+item.getExtra_data()+"'");}
    sb.append(" )");
```

**Here is the sample request:**

```
INSERT INTO goods_temp (item_title, item_descr, item_email, item_phone, item_images, item_price, owner, dateTime_created, category_id, subcategory_id, repost_to, type_sell, condo_name, condo_address, condo_location_type) VALUES ( 'HP Pavilion G7 17inch laptop', 'hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh', 'plimpa.contact@gmail.com', '65767657', '{}', '6456', 'plimpa.contact', 2017-07-04 14:53:14.045, 4, 21, '{}', true, 'hgfhgfh', 'fghgfhfghfgh', 'CONDO' ) RETURNING item_id;
```

**error i'm getting from it:**

```
nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "13"
```

**Question:**

How can i track which particular fields are formatted wrongly?

Comment: I can tell you that this timestamp `act', 2017-07-04 14:53:14.045, 4, 21,` needs single quotes. Sadly I don't know how to configure Spring in order to give more verbose error description. As a possible alternative you could check text logs of postgres to get more information.

Comment: Use a `PreparedStatement`. Do **not** concatenate values into SQL queries.